# Can a profile submission redirect to a PDF?

Tags: wordpress, profile, redirect

On CiviCRM 4.5/Wordpress 4.1, I'd like to create a profile that, when filled out, automatically downloads a PDF.  Is such a thing possible?  It didn't work when I put a URL to the PDF in the "Redirect URL" profile setting.  Is there another solution that's end-user friendly?  Could the [Redirect Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirect-editor/) plugin be of assistance here?

Comment: Do you mean that filling out the profile *generates* a pdf, or are you just talking about downloading a pre-existing file?

Comment: Downloading a pre-existing file.

Answer (score 2):

How about redirecting the user to a page that has the pdf download link? Granted its not automatic...